# How do I search for class constructors using R# Search Anywhere (Ctrl+T)?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, resharper, rider

How do I search for class constructors using R# Search Anywhere?

I've tried `className.className` without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it does not look like you can currently do that. The feature request is [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-484574/Search-everywhere-should-have-an-option-to-navigate-to-the-constructor-of-a-class-struct).